# How to change my C:\Users\(user-name) to match my user account name?

Tags: windows-7, windows, user-accounts

I already change my user account in control panel but the `C:\Users\(user-name)` is showing differently.

How do I change it to match my user account name?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it - here is a handy [how-to](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/147545-user-profile-folder-change-user-account-folder-name.html).

I probably would not take that approach however. I'd create a new account and transfer my data. I'd sync browser bookmarks, themes, add-ons etc. You can keep the old account until you are sure everything is working ok. Maybe not the quickest approach but works for me.